# Not able to upload managed package after using lightning:outputfield

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using lightning:outputfield on Lightning Component, all working fine but when I am uploading managed package then getting following error:-

> An internal server error has occurred
>   An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience. 
>   Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com! 
>   Error ID: 1091855389-33689 (57192470)

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="opportunityId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="verifier" type="Customer_Verifiers__c" default="{ sobjectType: 'Customer_Verifiers__c' }"/>
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.verifier.Id}" objectApiName="Customer_Verifiers__c"> 
    <span class="points">
        <lightning:outputField variant="label-hidden" fieldName="cverifiers__Weight__c"/>
    </span>
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

Comment: What is the API version component that wraps the lightning:recordViewForm?. If yes, can you try changing the API version to 41?. Since latter requires its wrapper component's API to be above 41 or above.

Comment: @Praveen its already 41

Comment: I am now getting Salesforce internal errors trying to upload a package as well. I don't think I added any new lightning elements to any components but seems there is a big issue at SF now. Curious to see if others have issues trying to upload managed packages when org is at v41

Comment: @Eric I am able to upload package without lightning:outputfield but getting error only when using lightning:outputfield. I was using force:outputfield previously which stopped working in Spring 18 Sandbox Preview sandboxes.

Comment: I am not using lightning:outputfield so there must be a larger issue at play here

Comment: Was told this is a known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A000000EQJz