# Package Upload Issue

Tags: managed-package, gack

I am trying to create a new version of existing managed package which results in Internal Server Error. I've some new components in package for implementing some new features. Added Lightning Components, Folder and Email Template in to package.

Also I've deleted list views in one of custom objects which is already part of package. Is this something which is causing error?

This is the Error ID: 1928119794-11108 (-997266957)

Has anyone faced issue like this?

Any Help...

Comment: I had the same issue. Turned out had a component that used an attribute that was no longer on the component itself. Lots of issues with api 42. Check to make sure any markup for a component does not use any attributes that may have been removed

Comment: Also check the known issue in this thread comments https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205977/not-able-to-upload-managed-package-after-using-lightningoutputfield#comment311085_205977

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have added a new field in existing fieldset and referred in apex class without checking whether the field is added in fieldset or not. So Salesforce throws an error message "SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: MyCustomObject.MyCustomField__c".
So we have modified our apex class to check whether the field is queried and then access its value.

Answer (score 2):

This type of error indicates that an error has occurred that hasn't been trapped by the platform - a low-level java exception for example.  All you can really do in terms of resolution is to file a support case with Salesforce and provide them the error ID that you are getting to get more information.

If you need to move quicker then, start removing functionality from the component to isolate where the problem occurs and see if there are any other mechanisms you can use.

[Submit a case to Salesforce Support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000123530&language=en_US&type=1)